# Target a product's attribute with CSS in WooCommerce/WordPress

Tags: css, class, attributes, woocommerce

I'm trying to target specific attributes of a product offered on a WordPress install running WooCommerce. Specifically I'm trying to target product-price & product-subtotal.

I've found what I believe to be the product ID class "postid-1539", and I've found the attributes I need to tweak ".product-price" & ".product-subtotal". But I can't specifically adjust the attributes for the specific product to display any differently.

Should I be tackling this with hooks & filters? I thought CSS would be the simplest way.

My in correct and NON-WORKING code looks like this

.postid-1539 .product-price {display;none:}

HALP. :P

Comment: Are the `.postid-1539`, `.product-price` are classes of the same element?

Comment: I think so, but that may not be so. If you wouldn't mind taking a look, this is the url, http://www.redbaycoffee.com/product/free-sample/ if you click "subscribe now" you'll be taken to the cart where you can inspect and perhaps help me. I'd simply like to target the price and total figures next to that specific product. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering by `targeting` an element you mean `selecting` an element to change it's styles. I can give you this solution:

```
.shop_table .product-price{ /* Font color of price is made green */
     color:Green;
}

.shop_table .quantity input.input-text{ /* Background color of quantity text box is made green */
     background:Green;
     color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Remember, you can select children element inside a parent element with `space` like this: `[parentTag/#parentId/.parentClass][SPACE][childrenTag/.childrenClass]`, in your example which is `.shop_table .product-price`. Where `.shop_table` is the class of the parent element and `.product-price` is the children element. So we selected them by their class with a `space` in between.

But to select an `input` element *with* class `.input-text`, you have to concatenate both like this: `input.input-text` which will change only the `input` elements with `.input-text` class but will not effect the other `input` elements with other classes.

To get a better knowledge of CSS Selectors visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) link.